# mongodb python get users of database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to create an admin application to monitor data collection. For this the user registration process is based on the database access i.e, when we create a new database user through MongoDB atlas, they will immediately be able to log into the admin application with their database username and password. How do I get a mongo document/response containing the list of database users and their hashed passwords using python?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, what have you tried till now?

Comment: @ngShravil.py I contacted MongoDB support but they said that code isn't shared on the free support tier.

Comment: Have you tried using the Atlas API for that?

Comment: @Joe atlas API? How do I use that?

Comment: the users are stored in `system.users` collection in the `admin` database

Comment: @Ayoub how can I make a call to the Atlas API and get the system.users with python?

Comment: @Ayoub could you specify how I can make a call to `system.users` in python? I have been trying to do such and also trying to access the atlas API. I have had no luck and the support team is not helping.

Comment: See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/#api

Comment: Yeah but I'm asking for how I can do this in python. I have tried many options such as accessing `admin.system.users` in python but I get `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [admin.system.users]`. Nobody has solved this issue not even Mongo's support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function that accepts the Mongo database user's username and password and uses that to connect to a Mongo client. I then attempt to perform a basic read operation (read operation requires the least user privilege) If the read op is successful then it means the username and password provides are authentic and I return true, else check if the operation failed because of a failed authentication and return false.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import OperationFailure

def check_dbuser(username, password):
    """ Attempts to connect to mongo atlas using the username and password. It then attempts a basic operation which is
        to list the database names of the cluster. If the operation works, the username and password are authentic and
        return True.
        Else if there is an OperationFailure we check that the error is due to failed authentication and return False

    """

    auth = False
    failed_message = 'bad auth Authentication failed.' # this is the err message returned on a failed authentication
    uri = f'mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster-connection-string'
    client = MongoClient(uri)

    try:
        client.list_database_names()
    except OperationFailure as e:
        assert(e.details['errmsg'] == failed_message) # assert that the error message is that of an authentication failure
    else:
        auth = True
    return auth
```

Comment: However, this isn't a complete solution. I would still need to implement a user class inheriting UserMixins and implement the @user_loader which both require I access to the mongodb atlas user database for session management.

Comment: I've handled the need for UserMixins by creating a cache of users